# If link exist between two nodes in Mininet API

Tags: python, networking, mininet, sdn

just wondering if there is any ways to check: if there is a link between two nodes (switches) by using Mininet python API?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the API from the mininet prompt:
Example:

mininet> **py s1.connectionsTo(s2)**

where s1 and s2 are the switches.

The topology looks like this:

```
mininet> **net**
h1 h1-eth0:s1-eth1
h2 h2-eth0:s2-eth1
h3 h3-eth0:s3-eth1
h4 h4-eth0:s4-eth1
s1 lo:  s1-eth1:h1-eth0 s1-eth2:s2-eth2
s2 lo:  s2-eth1:h2-eth0 s2-eth2:s1-eth2 s2-eth3:s3-eth2
s3 lo:  s3-eth1:h3-eth0 s3-eth2:s2-eth3 s3-eth3:s4-eth2
s4 lo:  s4-eth1:h4-eth0 s4-eth2:s3-eth3
c0
mininet> 
mininet> **py s1.connectionsTo(s2)**
[(<Intf s1-eth2>, <Intf s2-eth2>)] ---> This is the output which indicates      there is a link between s1 and s2 
mininet> 
mininet> 
mininet> **py s1.connectionsTo(s4)** 
mininet> --> No output, means no link between s1 & s4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ping()](http://mininet.org/api/classmininet_1_1net_1_1Mininet.html#a5a3d13340db0f440717364e17230512d) method to test the conectivity between 2 hosts. Or you may use [pingAll()](http://mininet.org/api/classmininet_1_1net_1_1Mininet.html#a4d979e7bbfbee700abd18b4372884f3c) method to test the complete network.